Set Position by using mesh islands in GeoNodes
I've divided my geometry into multiple mesh islands and stored a named integer attribute to identify which vertices belong to the same group. Then, I split edges to make some offset adjustments, and now I'm trying to set the position of points in the unchanged geometry to the nearest points in the modified geometry. But I can't figure out how to prevent it from going to the nearest point of a different island that's closer.
Ideally, I would like to use a unique integer for every vertex before splitting the edges, then match them back together using the same values.
Does anyone know if this is possible in GeoNodes?

Geometry nodes, how to select nearest edges of mesh islands or maybe Is there a way to limit "Geometry Proximity" to only instances that share the same instancer point? Otherwise maybe sketch or manually model what you want to achieve in geometry nodes? Cheers!

(Using Blender 3.6.12)
The following GeometryNodes modifier is shifting every mesh island away from one another, before calling a Geometry Proximity node to find the nearest node, in the split and modified geometry, to every node of the unchanged geometry, belonging to the same mesh island. Eventually, mesh islands are shifted back.

1. The offset between two mesh islands is set to 10% larger than the object Bounding Box to avoid any overlap between mesh islands.
2. For the demonstration, a Random offset is applied after splitting the edges.
Resources:
(Blender 3.6.12+)
